# Top bar help center linking

Tags: discussion, status-completed, top-bar

This is with reference to new Top bar implemented recently..

[image]

When you click in that link it points to [whats-meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) page. I think it must link to help center [home page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/) which was more clear and correct , considering we have detailed it as

> Detailed answers to ***any questions*** you might have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Ok you convinced me

> [image]

This is by design, and is just a special case for all metas. The most common use case for people clicking on help on a meta site is to ask the question "what the hell is this, and why is it different from the main site?".

Comment: Its kinda inconsistent, I think since we detailed it as `Detailed answers to any questions you might have` rather than `whats meta`... Also do you mean if the top bar gets implemented in all SE sites-- the help center will point to main help page.. only meta is special??

Comment: It's definitely inconsistent, but sometimes consistency isn't the ultimate goal.  All of the main sites will link straight to the help Center homepage, though.

Comment: You're easy to convince, only 5 votes were enough! ;-)