# Clicking on `Add Comment` used to focus on the comment area but it doesn't anymore

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, focus

Clicking on `Add Comment` used to focus on the comment area so one could start typing immediately instead of having to click in the textbox (unless I just imagined it)

Can we please reinstate that process (or create it if it never existed)?

I find myself clicking on `Add Comment` and typing for a couple seconds before realizing that the comment box was not focused and I was doing nothing...

Comment: Not sure if that ever existed.

Comment: Yes, this is _extraordinarily_ annoying!

Comment: @self. it most certainly did.

Comment: I thought so @AaronBertrand

Comment: So that's why recently I lost half of my comment ;) I guess touch typing should mean I'm not looking on my keyboard, not "not looking in the direction of a computer at all". And there I was, surprised I haven't typed anything.

Comment: The advantage of Firefox's "search as you type" feature is that you do not lose your content, it only appears in the search pane instead of the comment box :)

Comment: yep - this has annoyed me intensely. I had assumed I had b0rked something.

Comment: Good chance it's by design. Sometimes the dev team decides what's best for us.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - no more commenting for you.

Comment: @Oded <sad face> well, I was still under the influence of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208897/152859) which was by-designed ruthlessly. :D

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - one correction due then... Jeremy is not a dev ;)

Comment: @Oded well, the boss of the devs... ;)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the effort to add the `add comment` link to low rep and anonymous users, I flipped a Boolean condition around, but forgot to make the change down the line to the call that focuses the textarea.

The textarea will gain its focus on display once we build out (should be rev 2013.11.25.1177 (.1680 Meta), but with current DB woes, is is not clear when that happens).

Apologies to all, in particular the most prolific commenters.

Comment: DB woes? Did I miss something?

Comment: @qwertynl yes, it's [hot potato day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208853/152859) ;)

Comment: +1 Thanks @Oded, this became increasingly annoying as I got around to some real activity today.

Comment: Oh thank the heavens! And thank _you_.

Comment: \*ahem\* testing \*ahem\*

Comment: **now** you add comments for new users, huh? (after I painstakingly collected enough rep for commenting by old rules)

Comment: @DavidBalažic - Actually, no. The link is there, but it will tell you that 50 rep is needed...

Comment: @DavidBalažic it's just teasing.

Comment: Has anybody complained that clicking the "add comment" link shoots you to the top of the current page?

Comment: @Won't - Anonymous users? Yep. Fixed.

Comment: Yay, fixed! :-)

Comment: :| I assume it hasn't rolled out yet, then?  Because it's still happening.

Comment: @Won't - it has been rolled out. Can you describe the exact symptoms? Browser/OS? User type? Full/Mobile site?

Comment: Chrome, latest, win7, latest.  Repro'd just now.  I clicked the comment link in my inbox and was brought here.  I clicked the "add comment" link, at which point the browser scrolled all the way to the top instantly.  At this point, I can either start typing, in which case the browser scrolls the comment box into view, or I can scroll manually to bring it back into view.

Comment: @Won't - weird. Same setup, can't repro with your steps. Did you do a hard refresh/clear browser caches?

Comment: Hard refresh same same.  Not clearing my cache, tho.  I'd rather suffer than lose all my delicious cache goodness.

Comment: @Won't - bugger. I have no leads. Mind posting a bug report and what the `add link` markup looks like for you? And any JS errors, if you get them.

Comment: No js errors, one warning about event.returnValue().  Cleared cookies, local storage, and no change.  I might just have some plugin that's messing with me.  I'd have to take a look at that before I create a bug report...

Comment: @Oded don't want to spoil  the fun but looks like you did only [half job](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209612/152859) :(